# C# creating Chart from CSV data

Tags: c#, csv, charts

I tried to read a CSV Data and display it in a Chart in Visual Studio. I get a SystemArgument.Exception and it tolds me that he couldn't find the Column with the name "Date".

My Code is the following:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string file = "test.csv";
string dir = "C:\\Main";

string ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
            dir + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited\"";
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

string mySelectQuery = "Select * from " + file;
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

myCommand.Connection.Open();
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

chart1.Series["Test"].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "Date",myReader,"Value");
chart1.Series["Test"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

myReader.Close();
myConnection.Close();
}
```

What is wrong? I hope someone can help me... the .Csv data is:
Two columns - First column first row is Date
              Second Column first row is Value
The Rows in the first column look  01.04.2010 - the Rows in the second column look like 234.567

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `Select * from test.csv` will not work. Try this code

```
string file = @"C:\Main\test.csv";

string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
            file + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited\"";

string query = @"select * from sheetName$";
```

`sheetName` is the name of the csv sheet, you should replace it with the right value !

Be aware if the csv has column names HDR should be YES in connection string

I'm giving you working example with xslx file !

```
       string file = @"C:\Projects\EverydayProject\test.xlsx";

       string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                    file + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        string query = @"select * from [Table$]";

        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        using(OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
        {
            ad.Fill(tb);
        }

        conn.Close();
```

The sheetName is Table, look how I add `$` after the sheetName this is critical. Now in the tb you have the excel data !

Comment: Ok I tried that and it didn't help. I got a "OleDb.Exception" because the path seems incorrect. I did some changes and included the path to the file again and the full file name in the query string. Now he doesn't find the "Value" Column. When I change the "Value" in "chart1.Series["Test"].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "Date",myReader,"Value");" to "", he draws the graph but the Y-axis seems incorrect.

Comment: @uzi42tmp use DataTable and OleDbDataAdapter !

Comment: How shall i do that exactly?

Comment: i haven't that much experience in C#. What should I do with the Data Table and which values to put into the Axis to display the columns correctly?